# How to get custom response response at my own after add to cart(I want redirect to custom page after add to cart )

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, ajaxaddtocart

I am working with magento2, I want to create custom functionality after add to cart how to get a response on my own.
I need to redirect to custom page after add to cart product.

```
if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
        "catalogAddToCart": {}
        }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Please give me response about this

Comment: You should accept an answer to help other developers to find their right solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to custom page after addtocart then you should disable ajax addtocart by `"catalogAddToCart": {"bindSubmit": false}` read this ans for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155839/35758

You can use `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event to redirect to custom page after addtocart

Create `events.xml`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after_custompage" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterAddToCart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create `AfterAddToCart.php`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AfterAddToCart.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Test\Observer;

class AfterAddToCart implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct (
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customPageUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('mycustompage');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customPageUrl)->sendResponse();
        die();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to flush cache and di:compile