# Add to cart with ajax not working in homepage

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax

I installed Magento 2.2.5, and set Luma theme as default. In my homepage add to cart is not working with ajax, while on the other pages works just fine. 
Any idea?

Comment: Check your console browser errors

Comment: There is no errors in browser console.

Comment: can you try this solution ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125625/how-to-enable-ajax-for-the-the-add-to-cart-button-of-product-widgets-in-magent

Because default meagento luma theme does not provide ajax add to cart in widgets.

Comment: I tried every solution from your post, but unfortunately none worked for me.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: What part of code you want me to share? Its a clean installation of magento 2 with Luma theme? I just need some tips how can I add ajax functionality for add to cart in homepage.